# SQL: How do I count the number of times two events occurred within 15 mins of each other during a specific time range?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, time

I have two tables:

Table1 = equipment 
columns are 
- id 
- device_name

Table2 = equipment_events 
columns are  
- id (same id as in Table1) 
- timestamp 
- event_code

I want to be able to count the number of times a 'device_name' had the event_codes 'aaaa' and 'bbbb' occur within 15 minutes of each other with a data range of 2 days. And I want to group it by the device_name.

I was able to make a query looking for the event_code's separately within the 2 day range as an example below:

```
SELECT
  equipment.name, equipment_events.timestamp, COUNT(equipment_events.event_code)
FROM
  equipment
  INNER JOIN equipment_events ON (equipment_events.id=equipment.id)
WHERE
  equipment_events.event_code ='aaaa'
  AND equipment_events.timestamp BETWEEN '2017-02-01' and '2017-02-02'
GROUP BY equipment.name


SELECT
  equipment.name, equipment_events.timestamp, COUNT(equipment_events.event_code)
FROM
  equipment
  INNER JOIN equipment_events ON (equipment_events.id=equipment.id)
WHERE
  equipment_events.event_code ='bbbb'
  AND equipment_events.timestamp BETWEEN '2017-02-01' and '2017-02-03'
GROUP BY equipment.name
```

However, I am unable to figure out how to get a query to work where I am counting the number of times event_code 'bbbb' occurs within 15 mins of event_code 'aaaa' in that 2 day date range.

Comment: What if three or four events are all whithin a 15 minutes range?

Comment: And what is the primary key of `equipment_events`?

Comment: It is possible for event_code "aaaa" to occur and not "bbbb". It is also possible for "bbbb" to occur and not "aaaa". And it is also possible for "aaaa" to occur multiple times  before "bbbb" is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick. Edit: datediff in this manner is T-sql. I think TIMEDIFF(fromtime, totime) should work though.

```
SELECT
  equipment.name as EuipmentName
  --,eea.timestamp as A_Timestamp
  ,COUNT(eea.event_code) as A_Count
 -- ,eeb.timestamp as B_Timestamp
  ,count(eeb.Event_code) as B_Count
 -- ,datediff(minute,eea.timestamp,eeb.timestamp)
FROM
  equipment
  INNER JOIN equipment_events eea ON (eea.id=equipment.id)
    and eea.event_code = 'aaaa'
    and eea.timestamp BETWEEN '2017-02-01' and '2017-02-02'
inner join 
equipment_events eeb ON (eeb.id=equipment.id)
    and eeb.event_code = 'bbbb'
    and eeb.timestamp BETWEEN '2017-02-01' and '2017-02-02'


    WHERE TIMEDIFF(eea.timestamp,eeb.timestamp) <= 15 

GROUP BY equipment.name
```

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful.

Comment: I believe I am also beginning to realize that I only want to count the number of times event_code 'aaaa' and event_code 'bbbb' occur within 15 minutes of each other, but unique to each equipment.name.

This is a great starting point for me though. It was extremely helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the number of times an aaaa-event occured within 15 minutes after a bbbb-event or a bbbb-event occured within 15 minutes after an aaaa-event:

```
SELECT e.name, COUNT(DISTINCT ee2.timestamp)
FROM equipment_events ee1
JOIN equipment_events ee2
  ON  ee2.id = ee1.id
  AND ee2.event_code <> ee1.event_code
  AND ee2.timestamp  >= ee1.timestamp
  AND ee2.timestamp  <= ee1.timestamp + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE
JOIN equipment e ON e.id = ee1.id
WHERE ee1.event_code in ('aaaa', 'bbbb')
  AND ee2.event_code in ('aaaa', 'bbbb')
  AND ee1.timestamp BETWEEN '2017-02-01 00:00:00' and '2017-02-02 23:59:59'
  AND ee2.timestamp <= '2017-02-02 23:59:59'
GROUP BY ee1.id
```